# Reverse for 'evolucion_paciente' with arguments '(5,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['evolucion_paciente/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/(?P<id_e>[0-9]+)$']

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls, django-url-reverse

I have created a view that accepts 3 arguments but I get the following error in the homepage.Reverse for 'evolucion_paciente' with arguments '(5,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['evolucion_paciente/(?P[0-9]+)/(?P[0-9]+)$']

**Project/views.py** -- One of my views

```
def VerEvoluciones(request, id):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        paciente = Paciente.objects.get(id= id)
        evoluciones = Evolucion.objects.filter(paciente= id).order_by('-fechaEvolucion')
        evolucionForm = EvolucionForm()
    else:
        return redirect('index')

    return render(request, 'evoluciones.html', {'evolucionForm': evolucionForm, "Evoluciones": evoluciones, "Paciente": paciente})
```

Another View, and the one which im having troubles with

```
def VerEvolucion(request, id, id_e):
    evolucionForm= None
    evolucion= None
    try:
        if request.method == 'GET':
            paciente = Paciente.objects.get(id= id)
            evolucion = Evolucion.objects.filter(paciente= id).get(id= id_e)
            evolucionForm = EvolucionForm(instance= evolucion)
        else:
            return redirect('index')
    except ObjectDoesNotExist as e:
        error = e
    return render(request, 'evolucion.html', {'evolucionForm': evolucionForm,
                                                    'Evolucion': evolucion,
                                                    'Paciente': paciente,
                                                    'Ver': True})
```

In my template, the link that i need to redirect me from my firt view to my second one

```
<a href="{% url 'evolucion_paciente' evolucion.id %}" class="btn btn-warning">Ver</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the errors says, you defined a url pattern like:

```
evolucion_paciente/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/(?P<id_e>[0-9]+)$
```

so you need to pass *two* parameters, one for `id` and one for `id_e`. But in your `{% url … %}`, you only passed one:

```
{% url 'evolucion_paciente' evolucion.id %}
```

You need to pass an extra one:

```
<a href="{% url 'evolucion_paciente' value-for-id evolucion.id %}" class="btn btn-warning">Ver</a>
```

where you need to fill in `value-for-id` with the value for `id`. Probably something like:

```
<a href="{% url 'evolucion_paciente' evolucion.paciente.id evolucion.id %}" class="btn btn-warning">Ver</a>
```